# How can I display a Progress bar while copying files using Apache FileUtils? Android

Tags: android, file, io, apache-commons

I am using the [Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) commons library for copying files from one directory to another. The issue I am having is that I cannot figure out a way to update a progress bar when copying the file. My intial thought was to use a callback, but there is no way to pass in a callback to the copyfile method.

```
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(fileSrc, fileDest);
```

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem as below, May it will be useful to you.

```
if (mAdapter != null && mAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
    final ArrayList<StoryModel> selectedList = mAdapter.getSelectedData();

    if (selectedList.size() > 0) {

        final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setMessage("Saving Stories....");
        pd.show();

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    for (StoryModel imageModel : selectedList) {
                        String srcFilePath = imageModel.getUrl();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected: " + srcFilePath);
                        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(new File(srcFilePath), new File(FileUtils.getAppPath(mContext)));
                    }
                } catch (IOException ignored) {

                }
                Log.d(TAG, "run: Dismissed....");
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
        t.start();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.string_error_select_story_to_download, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} else {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.string_error_select_story_to_download, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Thank you :)